# Style personalizado para material ui React

Tags: react, syntax-error, drawer-layout

Estou tentando usar um component personalizado, como o código abaixo, mas o mesmo está dando erro, alguém pode me dar uma luz do por que está acontecendo o erro?

```
import React from 'react';
import {withStyles, createStyleSheet} from 'material-ui/styles'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Drawer} from 'material-ui';

const styleSheet = createStyleSheet({
  paper: {
    height: 'calc(100% - 64px)',
    top: 64
  }
})

class CustomDrawer extends React.Component {
 render () {
   const classes = this.props.classes
     return (
       <Drawer
        classes={{ paper: classes.paper}}
       />
      )
   }
 }

CustomDrawer.propTypes = {
 classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styleSheet)(CustomDrawer);
```

Esse erro está acontecendo e eu não estou entendendo

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
./src/components/CustomDrawer/CustomDrawer.jsx
src/components/CustomDrawer/CustomDrawer.jsx:

```
  3 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  4 | import {Drawer} from 'material-ui';
  5 | 
> 6 | const styleSheet = createStyleSheet({
  7 |     paper: {
  8 |       height: 'calc(100% - 64px)',
  9 |       top: 64
```

Comment: Por favor especifique a versao do Material UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importante: [`createStyleSheet()` foi removido na versão 1.0.0-beta.5](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e9c7c4422aa40b3bac196d465f8f1f9347d06c6e/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta5)

O seu problema é que não estás chamando a função com os argumentos corretamente.

Olhando no [código da versão 1.0.0-beta.4](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1.0.0-beta.4/src/styles/createStyleSheet.js#L8), segue o [arquivo de teste pra função em questão](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1.0.0-beta.4/src/styles/createStyleSheet.spec.js#L8), que afirma que a mesma leva os argumentos:

```
(name: string | GetStyles, callback?: GetStyles, options: Object = {})
```

Então, tente adicionar o primeiro argumento, uma string com o nome da folha de estilos, como foi usado no arquivo de teste:

```
createStyleSheet('nome', {
  paper: {
    height: 'calc(100% - 64px)',
    top: 64
  }
})
```

P.S. Você também pode tentar o seguinte:

```
createStyleSheet('nome', (theme) => {
  return {
    paper: {
      /* ... */
    },
  },
})
```

A chamada acima fornece como segundo argumento uma função callback que retorna o objeto com os estilos definidos.